# Node Js -Exception occurred executing command line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have started a  node js project and up to now I have included my html pages/css/etc in a folder named **'html'**. I have npm- installed the relevat modules also. But some error message is displayed during the launch. plz help me out.Thnx

**Project Hierarchy**

[image]

**squadra-server.njs**

```
  var express = require('express');
    var app = express.createServer();
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.send('Hello World');
    });
    app.configure(function () {
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/html'));
    })

    app.listen(8000);
```

**error msg**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the path to node.exe in your run configuration. Should not be much of a problem...